# Attach key with python code and set expiry time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to find a way to attach expire time/date to my program.Its same like to activate to use at first run, provide key and lets say after 30 days key will expire and again once I pass other key it will start working. Is there a way in python to do that , I want to attach this logic to my python code before I convert it to .exe so that exe work in that manner..

I do not have any code for this , need some hint to look around..

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a great example to post.

Comment: @Prune I know and agree with you what you have said , but I think its best place to get suggestion as unable to find a way . I want some hint or some related doc page ...

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

def encryption(line):
    return # some trapdoor encryption
key = encryption(time.time()+60*60*24*30)
```

then

```
import time

def decryption(line):
    return # line decrypted
if int(decryption(line)) > time.time():
    # give acces to what ever
```

that said anything can be cracked and this is not like some super secure method, just something ionce did :) hope it helps

Comment: thanks ! I thought some more idea , will try to implement that :)